# Issues getting CasperJS to upload image to file field - tried CasperJS fill() and PhantomJS uploadFile()

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to use CasperJS to upload images to a web-form.

My form looks something like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-vertical">
    ...                        
        <legend>Campaign Banner</legend>
        <div class="control-group image-field ">
            <label class="control-label">Now Large</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="file-field"><input id="id_now_large_image" name="now_large_image" type="file"></div>
                <div class="image-preview"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <span class="help-inline"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group image-field ">
            <label class="control-label">Now Medium</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="file-field"><input id="id_now_medium_image" name="now_medium_image" type="file"></div>
                <div class="image-preview"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <span class="help-inline"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group image-field ">
            <label class="control-label">Now Small</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="file-field"><input id="id_thumbnail_image" name="thumbnail_image" type="file"></div>
                <div class="image-preview now-small"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <span class="help-inline"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The submit button looks like this:

```
<div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Save changes</span></button>
</div>
```

I've put a Gist of the full HTML here: https://gist.github.com/victorhooi/8277035

First, I've tried using CasperJS's [fill](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fillxpath) method:

```
    this.fill('form.form-vertical', {
        'now_large_image': '/Users/victor/Dropbox/CMT Test Resources/Test Banners/Default Banners/now_large.jpg',
    }, false);
    this.click(x('//*[@id="content-wrapper"]//button/span'));
```

I also did a this.capture(), and I saw that the file field had been filled in:

[image]

I'm not using the fill method's inbuilt submit, but I'm clicking on the submit button myself:

this.click(x('//*[@id="content-wrapper"]//button/span'));

I then do another capture, and I can see that the form has been submitted:

[image]

However, the image doesn't seem to have been uploaded at all.

I've also tried using PhantomJS's [uploadFile()](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/upload-file.html) method:

```
this.page.uploadFile('input[name=now_large_image]', '/Users/victor/Dropbox/CMT Test Resources/Test Banners/Default Banners/now_large.jpg');
```

and then clicking on the submit button as well.

Same issue - the form field gets filled in - however, the image itself doesn't seem to get submitted.

Any ideas on how I can get the images to upload correctly here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are filling and submitting successfully, try a [Wait](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#wait) command on the click.

```
casper.then(function() {
    //+++ form fill here

    //waits 1 sec
    this.wait(1000, function() {
        this.click(x('//*[@id="content-wrapper"]//button/span'));
    });
});
```

Comment: @gumuruh - Good question. The entire code in that block is firing at once. Setting the wait redefines the stack here, i think. Technically, you could even drop a "setTimeout()" with a time of like 400 and it will redefine the stack, telling the code to run the click AFTER the previous stack, which would be the rest of the code in the block.

This is kinda what "casper.then" does for you as well. it redefines the stack. You could probably have surrounded each of the innards in casper.then and had a similar result.

Comment: exactly, i also thinking same for that. similar to setTimeout just like you said.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
casper.thenOpen('about:blank', function(){
    this.evaluate(function(){
        var action = 'upload.php'
        var html = '<form action="'+action+'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">'
        html += '<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple">'
        html += '<button type="submit">Submit</button>'
        html += '</form>'
        document.write(html)
    })
    this.fill('form',{
        'files[]': 'file.txt'
    }, true)
    this.waitFor(function(){
        var uri = casper.evaluate(function(){
            return document.documentURI
        })
        if ( 'about:blank' === uri ){
            return false
        }
        return true
    })
})
```